# How do you `$push` to a nested MongoDB array conditionally so that there are never 2 consecutive values the same?

Tags: mongodb

### Data structure

I collect readings from probes located at different locations. Readings are recorded as `{'value': <float>, 'when': <timestamp>}` in an array of `readings` and are ordered in ascending time order. The `readings` array is in a subdocument accessed by `probe_id`.

```json
{'location_id': ObjectId('6118d887066a0b17c9a4a531'),
    'probes': [
        {
            'probe_id': ObjectId('6118d887066a0b17c9a4a530'),
            'readings': [
                {'value': 42, 'when': Date("2021-08-12T05:25:28.905Z")},
                {'value': 37, 'when': Date("2021-08-12T08:34:30.405Z")},
                {'value': 43, 'when': Date("2021-08-12T12:56:45.043Z")},
                ...
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

### Full specification

1. Readings can be inserted into `readings` out of time order.
2. `readings` must remain sorted by ascending `when`.
3. There must never be 2 items in succession in `readings` with the same `value`.
4. When a `$push` would violate rule 3 then the new item must replace the old if (and only if) it has an earlier `when` (if `when` is a lower value), otherwise the `readings` should remain untouched.
5. The transaction must be atomic.

#### Bonus points

6. If a probe subdocument with `probe_id` is not present in `probes` then create the `{'probe_id':ObjectId(), 'readings':[]}` subdocument during the `$push`.

### Possible cases

1. empty list - Add item
2. push back, different value from preceding* member - Add item
3. push back, same value as preceding member - Do nothing (don't push)
4. push middle, different value from preceding and following** member - Add item
5. push middle, same value as preceding member - Do nothing (don't push)
6. push middle, same value as following member - Replace following member
7. push front, different value from following member - Add item
8. push front, same value as following member - Replace following member

*"preceding" = earlier in time (lower `when`)

**"following" = later in time (higher `when`)

#### Notes

- Items with identical `when` may either be ignored or replaced or be pushed (provided `value` between all items with identical `when` are different)
- From the point of optimization, we *normally* push back (insert with more recent, higher valued, `when`

### Current Code

Using PyMongo:

```py
result = collection.update_one(
    {'_id': location_id },
    {'$push': {'probes.$[probe].readings': {'$each': [new_reading], '$sort': {'when': 1}}}},
    array_filters = [{'probe.id': probe_id}],
)

if result.modified_count == 0:
    collection.update_one(
        {'_id': location_id },
        {'$push': {'probes': {'id': probe_id, 'readings': [new_reading]}}},
    )
```

Clearly this code does nothing to assert that consecutive items are of different values. It also fails to push the required subdocument if that is not present without 2 database calls. Is the above specification possible?

Comment: woah! that's asking too much from a database imho. whoever can come up with an answer to this, i will bow my head in respect ;-) alternatively you might wanna look in to time-series collections in mongodb 5 for automatic optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Online example for inserting `{"value" : 43 ,"when" : 11}`
Push middle, same value as following member - Replace following member
[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4eoetbGaDZH)

All possible cases (its 9 cases, 7 + 2 add on empty probes("bonus" case) or only empty readings)

```js
---------------------Empty probes(case 1(the extra case) empty probes)-------------------------------
Before add
{"_id": {"$oid": "61345b2aefdf45b6128444f2"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": []}
Case : Only 1 case exists Member : {value 41, when 3}
{"_id": {"$oid": "61345b2aefdf45b6128444f2"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"probe_id": 4, "readings": [{"value": 41, "when": 3}]}]}

---------------------Empty readings(case 1 empty readings)-------------------------------
Before add
{"_id": {"$oid": "61345b68efdf45b612844650"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"probe_id": 2, "readings": []}]}
Case : Only 1 case exists Member : {value 41, when 3}
{"_id": {"$oid": "61345b68efdf45b612844650"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"probe_id": 2, "readings": [{"value": 41, "when": 3}]}]}

---------------------Not empty readings-------------------------------
Before add
{"_id": {"$oid": "61346a33efdf45b6128496b7"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"probe_id": 2, "readings": [{"value": 42, "when": 5}, {"value": 37, "when": 10}, {"value": 43, "when": 15}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}]}]}
Case : NoConflict start[push front, different value from following member - Add item] Member : {value 41, when 3}
{"_id": {"$oid": "61346a33efdf45b6128496b7"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"probe_id": 2, "readings": [{"value": 41, "when": 3}, {"value": 42, "when": 5}, {"value": 37, "when": 10}, {"value": 43, "when": 15}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}]}]}
Case : Conflict start[push front, same value as following member - Replace following member] Member : {value 42, when 3}
{"_id": {"$oid": "61346a33efdf45b6128496b7"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"probe_id": 2, "readings": [{"value": 42, "when": 3}, {"value": 37, "when": 10}, {"value": 43, "when": 15}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}]}]}
Case : NoConflict middle[push middle, different value from preceding and following** member - Add item] Member : {value 42, when 11}
{"_id": {"$oid": "61346a33efdf45b6128496b7"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"probe_id": 2, "readings": [{"value": 42, "when": 5}, {"value": 37, "when": 10}, {"value": 42, "when": 11}, {"value": 43, "when": 15}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}]}]}
Case : Conflict middle[push middle, same value as preceding member - Do nothing (don't push)] Member : {value 37, when 11}
{"_id": {"$oid": "61346a33efdf45b6128496b7"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"probe_id": 2, "readings": [{"value": 42, "when": 5}, {"value": 37, "when": 10}, {"value": 43, "when": 15}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}]}]}
Case : Conflict middle[push middle, same value as following member - Replace following member] Member : {value 43, when 11}
{"_id": {"$oid": "61346a33efdf45b6128496b7"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"probe_id": 2, "readings": [{"value": 42, "when": 5}, {"value": 37, "when": 10}, {"value": 43, "when": 11}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}]}]}
Case : NoConflict end[push back, different value from preceding* member - Add item] Member : {value 47, when 21}
{"_id": {"$oid": "61346a33efdf45b6128496b7"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"probe_id": 2, "readings": [{"value": 42, "when": 5}, {"value": 37, "when": 10}, {"value": 43, "when": 15}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}, {"value": 47, "when": 21}]}]}
Case : Conflict end[push back, same value as preceding member - Do nothing (don't push)] Member : {value 41, when 21}
{"_id": {"$oid": "61346a33efdf45b6128496b7"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"probe_id": 2, "readings": [{"value": 42, "when": 5}, {"value": 37, "when": 10}, {"value": 43, "when": 15}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}]}]}
```

**Query**

- its big but its fast, its atomic, all done in 1 query, it doesn't sort the array,it inserts in the right position to keep it sorted
- to move this code to your code
  replace the 4 with new ObjectID() (add the method call)
  replace the 1 with the location ObjectID
  replace the 2 with the prob_id ObjectID
  i used numbers instead of dates for easy testing, but no need to change the query for that
- first `$set` is to define the new ObjectID(replace the 4 with the method call) in case probes is empty create the probe with empty readings
- `$map` to get inside the array
- `$reduce` to find the position where we will add the new member
  the `when` field defines the position, the query keep the array sorted by adding in the right place
  *we could use reduce to make the array not just find the position
  but if the array had >500 members because of concat it would be so slow not usable.
- when we have the position we check 4 basic cases

  - add at empty readings (1 case)
  - add at start (2 cases)
  - add at middle (3 cases)
  - add at end (2 cases)
  - each one of them has other cases if Conflict of `value` or not

```js
db.collection.update({
  "location_id": 1
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "prob-id": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$probes",
              []
            ]
          },
          4,
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "probes": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$probes",
              []
            ]
          },
          [
            {
              "probe_id": "$prob-id",
              "readings": []
            }
          ],
          "$probes"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "probes": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$probes",
          "as": "m1",
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              {
                "$ne": [
                  "$$m1.probe_id",
                  "$prob-id"
                ]
              },
              "$$m1",
              {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$m1",
                  {
                    "readings": {
                      "$let": {
                        "vars": {
                          "size_position": {
                            "$reduce": {
                              "input": "$$m1.readings",
                              "initialValue": [
                                0,
                                null,
                                null
                              ],
                              "in": {
                                "$let": {
                                  "vars": {
                                    "index_pos": "$$value",
                                    "m2": "$$this"
                                  },
                                  "in": {
                                    "$let": {
                                      "vars": {
                                        "index": {
                                          "$arrayElemAt": [
                                            "$$index_pos",
                                            0
                                          ]
                                        },
                                        "pos": {
                                          "$arrayElemAt": [
                                            "$$index_pos",
                                            1
                                          ]
                                        }
                                      },
                                      "in": {
                                        "$cond": [
                                          {
                                            "$and": [
                                              {
                                                "$eq": [
                                                  "$$pos",
                                                  null
                                                ]
                                              },
                                              {
                                                "$gt": [
                                                  "$$m2.when",
                                                  11
                                                ]
                                              }
                                            ]
                                          },
                                          [
                                            {
                                              "$add": [
                                                "$$index",
                                                1
                                              ]
                                            },
                                            "$$index"
                                          ],
                                          [
                                            {
                                              "$add": [
                                                "$$index",
                                                1
                                              ]
                                            },
                                            "$$pos"
                                          ]
                                        ]
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        "in": {
                          "$let": {
                            "vars": {
                              "asize": {
                                "$arrayElemAt": [
                                  "$$size_position",
                                  0
                                ]
                              },
                              "position": {
                                "$arrayElemAt": [
                                  "$$size_position",
                                  1
                                ]
                              }
                            },
                            "in": {
                              "$switch": {
                                "branches": [
                                  {
                                    "case": {
                                      "$eq": [
                                        "$$asize",
                                        0
                                      ]
                                    },
                                    "then": [
                                      {
                                        "value": 43,
                                        "when": 11
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "case": {
                                      "$eq": [
                                        "$$position",
                                        null
                                      ]
                                    },
                                    "then": {
                                      "$let": {
                                        "vars": {
                                          "prv_member": {
                                            "$arrayElemAt": [
                                              "$$m1.readings",
                                              {
                                                "$subtract": [
                                                  "$$asize",
                                                  1
                                                ]
                                              }
                                            ]
                                          }
                                        },
                                        "in": {
                                          "$cond": [
                                            {
                                              "$eq": [
                                                "$$prv_member.value",
                                                43
                                              ]
                                            },
                                            "$$m1.readings",
                                            {
                                              "$concatArrays": [
                                                "$$m1.readings",
                                                [
                                                  {
                                                    "value": 43,
                                                    "when": 11
                                                  }
                                                ]
                                              ]
                                            }
                                          ]
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "case": {
                                      "$eq": [
                                        "$$position",
                                        0
                                      ]
                                    },
                                    "then": {
                                      "$let": {
                                        "vars": {
                                          "next_member": {
                                            "$arrayElemAt": [
                                              "$$m1.readings",
                                              0
                                            ]
                                          }
                                        },
                                        "in": {
                                          "$cond": [
                                            {
                                              "$eq": [
                                                "$$next_member.value",
                                                43
                                              ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                              "$cond": [
                                                {
                                                  "$lt": [
                                                    11,
                                                    "$$next_member.when"
                                                  ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                  "$concatArrays": [
                                                    [
                                                      {
                                                        "value": 43,
                                                        "when": 11
                                                      }
                                                    ],
                                                    {
                                                      "$slice": [
                                                        "$$m1.readings",
                                                        1,
                                                        "$$asize"
                                                      ]
                                                    }
                                                  ]
                                                },
                                                "$$m1.readings"
                                              ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                              "$concatArrays": [
                                                [
                                                  {
                                                    "value": 43,
                                                    "when": 11
                                                  }
                                                ],
                                                "$$m1.readings"
                                              ]
                                            }
                                          ]
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                ],
                                "default": {
                                  "$let": {
                                    "vars": {
                                      "next_member": {
                                        "$arrayElemAt": [
                                          "$$m1.readings",
                                          "$$position"
                                        ]
                                      },
                                      "prv_member": {
                                        "$arrayElemAt": [
                                          "$$m1.readings",
                                          {
                                            "$subtract": [
                                              "$$position",
                                              1
                                            ]
                                          }
                                        ]
                                      }
                                    },
                                    "in": {
                                      "$switch": {
                                        "branches": [
                                          {
                                            "case": {
                                              "$and": [
                                                {
                                                  "$ne": [
                                                    "$$next_member.value",
                                                    43
                                                  ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                  "$ne": [
                                                    "$$prv_member.value",
                                                    43
                                                  ]
                                                }
                                              ]
                                            },
                                            "then": {
                                              "$concatArrays": [
                                                {
                                                  "$slice": [
                                                    "$$m1.readings",
                                                    0,
                                                    "$$position"
                                                  ]
                                                },
                                                [
                                                  {
                                                    "value": 43,
                                                    "when": 11
                                                  }
                                                ],
                                                {
                                                  "$slice": [
                                                    "$$m1.readings",
                                                    "$$position",
                                                    {
                                                      "$add": [
                                                        "$$asize",
                                                        1
                                                      ]
                                                    }
                                                  ]
                                                }
                                              ]
                                            }
                                          },
                                          {
                                            "case": {
                                              "$eq": [
                                                "$$prv_member.value",
                                                43
                                              ]
                                            },
                                            "then": "$$m1.readings"
                                          }
                                        ],
                                        "default": {
                                          "$concatArrays": [
                                            {
                                              "$slice": [
                                                "$$m1.readings",
                                                0,
                                                "$$position"
                                              ]
                                            },
                                            [
                                              {
                                                "value": 43,
                                                "when": 11
                                              }
                                            ],
                                            {
                                              "$slice": [
                                                "$$m1.readings",
                                                {
                                                  "$add": [
                                                    "$$position",
                                                    1
                                                  ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                  "$add": [
                                                    "$$asize",
                                                    1
                                                  ]
                                                }
                                              ]
                                            }
                                          ]
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "prob-id"
    ]
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 2**

Online example for `{"probe_id" : 2, "readings" : [{"value" :43 ,"when" : 11}]}`
[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gaoDkOGPxYO)

All possible cases (its 9 cases, 7 + 2 add on empty probes("bonus" case) or only empty readings)

```js
---------------------Empty probes-------------------------------
Before add
{"_id": {"$oid": "61356ae9fdad8624e245e271"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": []}
Case : Only 1 case exists[empty list - Add item(the bonus case)] Member : {:probe_id 2, :readings [{value 42, when 3}]}
{"_id": {"$oid": "61356ae9fdad8624e245e279"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"readings": [{"value": 42, "when": 3}], "probe_id": 2}]}

---------------------Empty readings-------------------------------
Before add
{"_id": {"$oid": "61356b73fdad8624e245e58c"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"probe_id": 2, "readings": []}]}
Case : Only 1 case exists[empty list - Add item] Member : {:probe_id 2, :readings [{value 42, when 3}]}
{"_id": {"$oid": "61356b73fdad8624e245e594"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"readings": [{"value": 42, "when": 3}], "probe_id": 2}]}

---------------------Not empty readings-------------------------------
Before add
{"_id": {"$oid": "613569f7fdad8624e245dd01"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"readings": [{"value": 42, "when": 5}, {"value": 37, "when": 10}, {"value": 43, "when": 15}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}], "probe_id": 2}]}
Case : NoConflict start[push front, different value from following member - Add item] Member : {:probe_id 2, :readings [{value 41, when 3}]}
{"_id": {"$oid": "61356a2dfdad8624e245de34"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"readings": [{"value": 41, "when": 3}, {"value": 42, "when": 5}, {"value": 37, "when": 10}, {"value": 43, "when": 15}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}], "probe_id": 2}]}
Case : Conflict start[push front, same value as following member - Replace following member] Member : {:probe_id 2, :readings [{value 42, when 3}]}
{"_id": {"$oid": "61356a2dfdad8624e245de3d"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"readings": [{"value": 42, "when": 3}, {"value": 37, "when": 10}, {"value": 43, "when": 15}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}], "probe_id": 2}]}
Case : NoConflict middle[push middle, different value from preceding and following** member - Add item] Member : {:probe_id 2, :readings [{value 42, when 11}]}
{"_id": {"$oid": "61356a2dfdad8624e245de46"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"readings": [{"value": 42, "when": 5}, {"value": 37, "when": 10}, {"value": 42, "when": 11}, {"value": 43, "when": 15}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}], "probe_id": 2}]}
Case : Conflict middle[push middle, same value as preceding member - Do nothing (don't push)] Member : {:probe_id 2, :readings [{value 37, when 11}]}
{"_id": {"$oid": "61356a2efdad8624e245de4f"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"readings": [{"value": 42, "when": 5}, {"value": 37, "when": 10}, {"value": 43, "when": 15}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}], "probe_id": 2}]}
Case : Conflict middle[push middle, same value as following member - Replace following member] Member : {:probe_id 2, :readings [{value 43, when 11}]}
{"_id": {"$oid": "61356a2efdad8624e245de59"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"readings": [{"value": 42, "when": 5}, {"value": 37, "when": 10}, {"value": 43, "when": 11}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}], "probe_id": 2}]}
Case : NoConflict end[push back, different value from preceding* member - Add item] Member : {:probe_id 2, :readings [{value 47, when 21}]}
{"_id": {"$oid": "61356a2efdad8624e245de62"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"readings": [{"value": 42, "when": 5}, {"value": 37, "when": 10}, {"value": 43, "when": 15}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}, {"value": 47, "when": 21}], "probe_id": 2}]}
Case : Conflict end[push back, same value as preceding member - Do nothing (don't push)] Member : {:probe_id 2, :readings [{value 41, when 21}]}
{"_id": {"$oid": "61356a2efdad8624e245de6b"}, "location_id": 1, "probes": [{"readings": [{"value": 42, "when": 5}, {"value": 37, "when": 10}, {"value": 43, "when": 15}, {"value": 41, "when": 20}], "probe_id": 2}]}
```

Query

- uses another method, with lookup
- adds the reading in the end, sorts the array by when
- removes and element if the previous member has the same value
  (this way we keep only the members with the smaller when)
- uses merge for the update, its not possible with update even with
  pipeline to do those, because we need lookup and group etc
  *merge requires a unique index on  location_id else wont work
  *online example doesnt have the merge, query bellow has it

Drawback

- if someone else add readings in the same location_id, while we update that location_id document (its very small thim) but stil if
  concurency of milliseconds is important it might cause data loss.

*You can use the logic of this query and parts of the code with transaction if you prefer smaller but more queries.
For example add in the end, sort array (1 query), remove duplicate values (second query) etc, but you dont need solution2 or transactions, solution1 does all in 1 query + atomic but ok

```js
db.testcoll.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "location_id": {
        "$eq": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "prob-id": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$probes",
              []
            ]
          },
          4,
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "probes": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$probes",
              []
            ]
          },
          [
            {
              "probe_id": "$prob-id",
              "readings": []
            }
          ],
          "$probes"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "testcoll1",
      "let": {
        "probes": "$probes"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$set": {
            "probes": {
              "$concatArrays": [
                "$$probes",
                [
                  {
                    "probe_id": 2,
                    "readings": [
                      {
                        "value": 43,
                        "when": 11
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$unwind": {
            "path": "$probes"
          }
        },
        {
          "$unwind": {
            "path": "$probes.readings"
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            "probes.probe_id": 1,
            "probes.readings.when": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$probes"
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "probes"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "probes": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$probes",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$let": {
              "vars": {
                "ps": "$$value",
                "p": "$$this"
              },
              "in": {
                "$let": {
                  "vars": {
                    "prv_p": {
                      "$last": "$$ps"
                    }
                  },
                  "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                      {
                        "$and": [
                          "$$prv_p",
                          {
                            "$eq": [
                              "$$prv_p.readings.value",
                              "$$p.readings.value"
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "$eq": [
                              "$$prv_p.probe_id",
                              "$$p.probe_id"
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "$eq": [
                              "$$p.probe_id",
                              2
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      "$$ps",
                      {
                        "$concatArrays": [
                          "$$ps",
                          [
                            "$$p"
                          ]
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "testcoll1",
      "let": {
        "probes": "$probes"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$set": {
            "probes": "$$probes"
          }
        },
        {
          "$unwind": {
            "path": "$probes"
          }
        },
        {
          "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$probes"
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$probe_id",
            "readings": {
              "$push": "$readings"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$set": {
            "probe_id": "$_id"
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "probes"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "_id",
      "prob-id"
    ]
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
        "into": {
          "db": "testdb",
          "coll": "testcoll"
        },
        "on": [
          "location_id"
        ],
        "whenMatched": "replace",
        "whenNotMatched": "discard"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Another impressive answer from you! From what I understand solution 2 has a potential race condition. Aside from being easier to read, what are the benefits of solution 2 over solution 1? I should note that the readings array has the potential to get very large indeed. Also, you mention that the race condition may lead to data loss - this would be acceptable provided that duplicate values would not occur.

Comment: i dont see any benefits, i just wrote it because i was curious of smaller ways, Solution1 is fast(doesnt even sort, inserts in place) and atomic. Solution 2 is smaller query and its for small arrays <1000 members else slow + that atomic possible problem.Solution3 could be a transaction with 2 queries 1 add in the end and sort,
and 2 remove the duplicate value.But this is like reduce with state(remember previous), so you have to do it fast(solution2 does it but with concatArrays=> slow for big arrays), you can benchmark and see but solution1 is fast+safe i think.